# Internal non-static class. The right approach? WebSocket

Tags: java, class, websocket

Prompt the correctness of such a decision.

I have a connection point for the web socket on Java (server). It implements the `onOpen`, `onMessage`, `onClose`, and `onError` methods.

It's about the `onMessage` method.

I do not want to stuff this method with a switch that will be huge for all the messages that are possible.

I did this kind of thing (I used an internal non-static class for processing messages)

```
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/endpoint", configurator = SocketConfigurator.class, encoders = WsEncoder.class, decoders = WsDecoder.class)
public class WsEndpoint {

    private static final CopyOnWriteArrayList<WsUser> wsWebUsers = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<WsUser>();

    public WsEndpoint() {
        LOGGER.info("ENDPOINT CREATED");
    }

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) {
        LOGGER.info("ENDPOINT ONOPEN");
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(Session session, WsMessage wsMessage) {

        new WsOnMessage(session, wsMessage);

    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session) {

    }

    @OnError
    public void onError(Session session, Throwable ex) {
        LOGGER.error("ENDPOINT ERROR", ex);
    }

    private class WsOnMessage {

        private Session session;
        private WsMessage wsMessage;

        WsOnMessage(Session session, WsMessage wsMessage) {
            this.session = session;
            this.wsMessage = wsMessage;
            execute();
        }

        private void execute() {
            switch (wsMessage.getType()) {
            default:
                LOGGER.info("ENDPOINT UNKNOWN MESSAGE");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is it true to do so? Can there be a more elegant way of handling messages?

Thank you.

Comment: I'd use the factory and command patterns.

Comment: @M.leRutte can you paste example? please

Answer (score 1):

Create an abstract class of which the `execute` method is overridden by its subclasses:

```
public abstract class Command {
  protected final Session session;
  protected final WsMessage message;

  public Command(Session session, WsMessage message) {
    this.session = session;
    this.message = message;
}


  public abstract void execute();
}
```

Create command factory that knows how to map a `WsMessage` to a corresponding `Command` class:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

public class CommandFactory {
  private <T extends Command> Class<T> findCommandClass(WsMessage message) {
    // switch on message, or lookup in a Map<WsMessage,Class<? extends Command>>, or,...
    // throw exception if no registered class
    throw new RuntimeException(String.format("No known command for message %s", message));
}

  private <T extends Command> T createInstance(Class<T> clazz, Session session, WsMessage message) {
    try {
        Constructor<T> constructor = clazz.getConstructor(Session.class, WsMessage.class);
        return constructor.newInstance(session, message);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Could not instantiate  %s", clazz), e);
    }
  }

public Command createCommand(Session session, WsMessage message) {
    Class<Command> commandClass = findCommandClass(message);
    return createInstance(commandClass, session, message);
}
}
```

In `WsEndpoint` have a reference to the factory:

```
public class WsEndpoint {
   private CommandFactory factory;

   // if you are required to have a no-arg default constructor and can't use dependency injection:
   public WsEndpoint() {
       this(new MyStandardCommandFactory()); // create an instance of the standard command factory.
   }

   public WsEndpoint(CommandFactory factory) {
       this.factory = Objects.requireNonNull(factory);
   }

   @OnMessage
   public void onMessage(Session session, WsMessage wsMessage) {
        Command command = factory.createCommand(session, wsMessage);
        command.execute();
   }
```

This pattern will allow you to pass a mocked command factory for testing.

Some thoughts:

- Make CommandFactory abstract and the find method protected with a default implementation of throwing an exception
- Maybe pass the `Session` only as a parameter of execute, not to the factory.

Comment: tell me please. how i can access to a my list users which connected on my websocket? this list is static, thread-safe List

Comment: I don't know. I think that is a different question you are asking. Maybe accept this one and create a new question.